# Capture old Appointment/Event record values using workflow action script in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have an Appointment record and the user can edit and change the "Appointment Date" and "Time" fields. While saving the record a workflow action script will be triggered to do some actions. Simultaneously I want to capture the old "Appointment Date and Time" and compare with the changed date and time. Is there a way to do this in the workflow action script 1.0? Please help me to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I created a workflow variable which captures the appointment old value (by keeping the event as Entry). At the same time, I created a script variable and pushes the workflow variable value to this script variable in the workflow. Then by using the below code I got the script variable in my script.

```
context.getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_myscript_param');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping 'Trigger Type' as "After Record Submit".

You can get old value and new value in the same script with below code,

```
var newRecord = context.newRecord;
var oldRecord = context.oldRecord;
var newStartDate = newRecord.getValue('startdate');
var oldStartDate = oldRecord.getValue('startdate');
```

Compare newStartDate value and oldStartDate value.
Similar will be the logic for Time field.

Comment: Thanks @Sid for the info. I will check and confirm.

Comment: @Ba.Lal was this helpful?

Comment: If possible, share more information about it. I will be happy to check why it is not working for you.